# Laravel MySql возвращает строки вместо чисел

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, hosting

Я написал приложение на Laravel+vue (Плюс использую axios), на моей локальной машине всё работает исправно. Но на хостинге все данные из БД являются строками, кроме `id`.

Вот результат, который приходит с хостинга (nginx)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот, что приходит на моей локальной машине (У меня Ubuntu Apache)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю, что проблема в окружении, то есть в хостинге.
Вот скрин из phpMyAdmin на хостинге (Сервер работает на 5.4.16, но при этом в панели управления у меня выбрана версия 7.4.20)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот скрин моей локальной машины, и здесь используется mysqlnd (Насколько я знаю, он как раз и отвечает за то, что представлять числа, как числа, а не строки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я писал в поддержку и изменить версию php там нельзя.
7.4.20 у меня сконфигурирован с модулем mysqlnd.
5.4.16 нельзя сконфигурировать с mysqlnd.

Как исправить это недоразумение?

Вот драйвер, который я использую в laravel на хостинге

```js
'mysql' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  'prefix_indexes' => true,
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => null,
  'options' => []
];
```

Comment: Код по созданию объектов покажете?

Comment: что это за хостинг древний такой?))

Comment: Хостинг - smart ape

Comment: @AntonShchyrov - я использую laravel: `Bird::all()`, например. И потом в контроллере это просто через return возвращается, есть места, где через response()->json() - результат один и тот же. Можно через dump вывести - тоже строка будет.

Comment: В phpinfo() на сервере в mysql -> client api library version = 5.6.68-MariaDB. А на локалке mysqlnd 7.3.4

Answer (score 0):

В настройках моей версии php на сервере (7.4.20) я включил расширение `nd_pdo_mysql` и мне стали приходить числа!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь я кому-то помогу